# {{ dump( variable_name ) }} not working in opencart-3

Tags: opencart-3

I think there is not any config option to turned on twig template debug in opencart 3.0.2.0.if wrong do correct and suggest solution to solve this.

{{ dump() }}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:
Go to system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php
In $options array. Set 'debug' option to 'true'
at the bottom add:

```
$this->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

Comment: I would also change debug option to something like: 'debug' => TWIG_DEBUG and define constant in config.php, e.g. define('TWIG_DEBUG', true). Easier to change. But this is just a convenience and not needed.